# Running ASP.NET MVC 2 project not in root of the domain, but in folder

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

Good day!

I need to run ASP.NET MVC application not in the root of the server (like http://example.com), but in the folder (I think in will be configured as virtual folder in IIS), say: http://example.com/mymvcapp

For now all routing helpers generate urls from the root with trailing slash, like `/controller/action/id`.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Url helpers always generate correct routes and take into consideration the virtual directory your application runs in. So if you have a virtual directory called `mymvcapp` in IIS under the site root and you deploy your application inside the physical folder this directory is pointing to when you write:

```
<%: Url.Action("index", "home") %>
```

This will generate*:

```
/mymvcapp/home/index
```

<sup>* assuming default routes obviously</sup>